# After putting values in MainActivitiy , how to make when opening the app to open the SecondActivity with the data saved from main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Do you know how to make for example : after putting some values to the activity(1) , you close the app and then reopen it and it starts on the next activity(2) with a saved information of the values from activity(1)?

I managed to transfer values after writing down in EditText in activity(1) and after clicking a button to transfer to activity(2) + transferring the values from activity(1) aswell.

This is my code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText enterHeight, enterWeight, enterAge;

private double height;
private double weight;
private double age;
String selectedRadiobut;
Button button;
RadioButton radioMale, radioFemale;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
SharedPreferences sp;
private boolean heightIsValid() {

    if (enterHeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        enterHeight.setError("Cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    double height = Double.valueOf(enterHeight.getText().toString());

    if (height <= 0) {

        enterHeight.setError("Cant be zero");
        return false;
    }
    if (height <= 40 || height > 250) {

        enterHeight.setError("Cant be less than 40 cm or more than 250 cm");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean weightIsValid() {
    if (enterWeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        enterWeight.setError("Cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    double weight = Double.valueOf(enterWeight.getText().toString());

    if (weight <= 0) {

        enterWeight.setError("Cant be zero");
        return false;
    }
    if (weight > 600) {

        enterWeight.setError("Cant be more than 600 kg");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean ageIsValid() {
    if (enterAge.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        enterAge.setError("Cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    double age = Double.valueOf(enterAge.getText().toString());

    if (age <= 0) {

        enterAge.setError("Cant be zero");
        return false;
    }
    if (age > 116) {

        enterAge.setError("Cant be older than 116 years");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean genderIsSelected() {

    if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) { //checking if the user has selected a option using id
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please select gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return false;
    }
    if (radioMale.isChecked()) {
        selectedRadiobut = radioMale.getText().toString();
    }
    else if (radioFemale.isChecked()) {
        selectedRadiobut = radioFemale.getText().toString();
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    radioMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
    radioFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    enterHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterHeight);
    enterWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterWeight);
    enterAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAge);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

    sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (heightIsValid() & weightIsValid() & ageIsValid() & genderIsSelected()) {

                height = Double.valueOf(enterHeight.getText().toString());
                weight = Double.valueOf(enterWeight.getText().toString());
                age = Double.valueOf(enterAge.getText().toString());

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("height" , String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) height)));
                editor.putString("weight" , String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) weight)));
                editor.putString("age" , String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) age)));
                editor.putString("gender", String.valueOf(selectedRadiobut));
                editor.commit();

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is my second activity:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
Button  btnMC , btnFN , btnRec , btnGuides;
    public void btnStepClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StepCounter.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void btnCalClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MacrosCalculator.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void btnRecClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recipes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        TextView age1 , height1 , weight1 , gender1;

        age1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age1);
        height1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.height1);
        weight1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weight1);
        gender1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender1);
        btnMC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMC);
        btnFN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFN);
        btnRec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRec);
        btnGuides = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuides);

        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String height = sp.getString("height" , "");
        String weight = sp.getString("weight" , "");
        String age = sp.getString("age" , "");
        String gender= sp.getString("gender", "");

        gender1.setText("Gender: " + gender);
        age1.setText("Age: " + age);
        height1.setText("Height(cm): " + height);
        weight1.setText("Weight(kg): " + weight);


    }
}
```

So how to make it after putting values in Height, Weight, Age and Gender and closing the app after opening it again to start on the Activity 2 with the values that you putted in the previous start of the application? :D

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save values to shared preferences when the user fills them in Activity 1.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

// Save your values
editor.putString("keyName", "value");
// ... save other values ...

// Apply the changes
editor.apply();
```

create another value for the the user complete with activity 1

```
editor.putBoolean("Activity1Complete", true);
editor.apply();
```

in your mainActivity check the valued

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isActivity1Complete = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Activity1Complete", false);

if (isActivity1Complete) {
    // Start Activity 2
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    // If you stored values from Activity 1 in shared preferences, retrieve them here and pass them with the intent
    String value = sharedPreferences.getString("keyName", "");
    intent.putExtra("keyName", value);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // This will close the launcher activity so that when the user presses the back button they won't come back to the launcher
} else {
    // Start Activity 1
}
```

Comment: I've editted my post . I posted the code of the two activities. :)

Comment: Yoo, thanks for the good answer , after taking this example and putting some of the things that you've shown me , i managed to do it on my code! Thank you a LOT!!!!